# Analysis of Algorithm - Time Complexity of three nested dependent loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, execution-time

Hi I'm trying to analyze the time complexity of this algorithm but I'm having difficult unraveling and counting how many times the final loop will execute.

```
for(int i =1; i<=n; i++){
    for (int j=i; j<=n; j++) {
        for (int k =1; k<=j; k++){
            // Any statment
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear? Have you heard about arithmetic progression sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the analysis of time complexity, each loop statement is represented by a sum. So, you have to solve the following calculation representing nested loops:

[image: complexity calculation]

Which is equal to: [image: Result]

Comment: You don't add the `k`'s because there is no loop of length `k`.

Comment: True. Thanks @meowgoesthedog